# How to capture network trafic in c# when loading a website like the browser development tool does in the network tab

Tags: c#, get, network-traffic

Im trying to capter trafic of a localy hosted website used in a industrial camera. Because i want to save the image and do processing on it. The image can be viewed on a web page. There is no other way of getting the image out of the camera.

[image: image i need to capture from the request]

I tried using Fiddlercore for c#, however it seems that there is no support for this nuget package anymore. It doesnt work like described.

The camera generates a new unique url for every new image, so i cant just copy One static requst. I need to know the new name of the image every time i want to make the request myself.
Anyone knows how to call the base url of the website and capture the get request, so i can mimick the request myself and save the image?

tried to use Fiddlecore to get the get request.

Comment: If the browser is issuing a GET request for the image surely it must know the name of the image in advance? if so thats the logic you should try to copy.  If its doing someting with a websocket push then hosting a browser control in your app is another options.

Comment: Are you even sure if you had the url it could be used twice? Does the webcam buffer the image or do you need the image data not just the url.

Comment: Can't you scrape that page instead of capturing low-level traffic? With HTML Agility pack or alternatives you should be able to pull that off